# "Xcode could not determine type of profile" error from xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode

When building with `xcodebuild`, it returns the following error:

```
xcodebuild[39801:1441114]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-14490.122/IDEFoundation/Provisioning/IDEProfileQualification.m:509
Details:  Xcode could not determine type of profile "/Users/xxxx/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/88a31133-a95d-4ae2-b516-f86dffe2f432.mobileprovision" (could be {(
)})
Object:   <IDEProfileQualification: 0x7fc8808118f0>
Method:   -_profileTypeQualifier
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc8766457e0>{number = 6, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple updated the developer portal UI and I didn't read the description carefully. The certificate and profile I created works only for Xcode 11.

The correct choice for Xcode10 is **"iOS Distribution (App Store and Ad Hoc)"**.

[image]

Comment: I love Apple break things without even documenting the new certificate type and removing references to the old type.